# How to select elements that have CSS styles that contain specific values

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to select the elements that have style settings that contain a given color under different forms. It is for making a button that changes the colors on a page for several elements t the same time, some bearing say the pink color, other having a `border:solid 1px #F08` setting, others even having transparent versions of that color in their "box-shadow" setting.

So for instance it shows up as this CSS:

```
.element a {
  color: #ff0088
}
 
.element p {
  linear-gradient(to right, #57002e, #f08, #57002e) <- (shades of "#F08")
}

.element li {
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px #f08;
  border: solid 2px #ff008870 !important; <- (another shade of "#F08")
}

.element div {
  background-color: #F08
}
```

...and I'm trying to select all those elements automatically as their css values contain given colors, in order to either change those to other given values.

I have tried a :

```
var ToSelect = $('*').css('background,background-color,color,border').val('#F08');
```

and

```
var ToSelect = $('*').css('background,background-color,color,border').contains('#F08');
```

as a start but it gives a jQuery error. So I have no idea how to get that simple thing to work and would greatly appreciate your quick input here, as always.

Comment: You won't be able to select elements by specific CSS properties. I think you would be best to use a specific class or classes that contain these properties.

Comment: For example, see: https://jsfiddle.net/76484/tm4bLj82/

Comment: Can you please share a representative sample of your HTML and CSS, and clearly explain which element(s) should be changed, what they should be changed to, and *why* (*especially* if there's some logic or requirements involved).

Comment: @David Thomas : Say, I have designed my company's page with a given color, pink, and was trying to offer viewers the ability to change all pink and pink shaded elements by clicking a button to say blue, using "color:" ,"background-color", "border:", and maybe "filter:hue-rotate(). But as 76484 says it seems it is not possible using contains(), html(), text(). As you mention the logic it's what I was curious about, but there's no way I see that lets me alter the "#F08" in "border: solid 2px #F08", or within a "text-shadow" property for instance.

Comment: @David Thomas  If you'd like me to show you the website I will gladly send you the link through a private message which I guess is possible here but I guess you will see just another website with its own graphic design and colors. The code itself may prove a disappointment as I am a very amateurish coder who has managed to make his own website thank to StackOverflow, and to you all, its users.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think I could write an answer that solves the problem for you as I understand it; instead I think you need to look for tutorials on the use of CSS custom properties (YouTube has videos from people like [Kevin Powell](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5QIiWIoCmsc), [Una Kravitz](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HxJnvCOC2vQ)), but as a simple illustrative demo: https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/2ja0no67/. There's also articles at [A list Apart](https://alistapart.com/) and [Smashing Magazine](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/), among others.

Comment: @DavidThomas Thank you very much for your input,  I will look into that with interest, although I'm a photo retoucher and already am very happy with what the knowledge I've found -or what I've learnt on StackOverflow and the website I was able to make for my own company. I mean it looks very interesting but way above my own skills at coding :p Thank you again.